# Can I buy a standard SSL certificate to protect a website i.e. certificates.xxxxxx.com?

Tags: tls, websites, sub-domain

I don't have much experience in buying and installing ssl certificates.

I have one website like certificates.xxxxx.com. So, my question is that can I buy a standard ssl certificate from GoDaddy to protect this one website.

xxxxx.com itself is a website which is protected by a website but I want to buy a separate for certificates.xxxxx.com.

Comment: In general one can get a certificate for a domain one owns. What a specific company (GoDaddy) offers for its customers is off-topic here though.

Comment: If you can manage, free Let's Encrypt certificates with automatic renewal are arguably better than paid yearly certificates.